# For untrusted user upload sites: what should the contents of crossdomain.xml and clientaccesspolicy.xml be?

Tags: appsec, web-application, xss, flash

Flash has a long history of ignoring MIME types of files and reading the file directly for executable content or for cross domain execution permissions.  That means a malicious user can take advantage of this to create XSS flaws on the same domain as my other secured services.

Since I will not be serving flash from my site, and the presence of a flash document in the same domain will cause a security risk, I want to block all Flash-initiated XSS actions.

What is the recommended content of `crossdomain.xml` or `clientaccess.xml`?

Comment: Related: [How to configure this in IIS/AD's config file to issue the correct MIME type](http://serverfault.com/q/366411/51457)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With regard to Flash issues, every site that doesn't use Flash should use one of the two files at the root of the web server named `crossdomain.xml`.  This will prevent XSS via that plugin

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM  
 "http://www.adobe.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">

<cross-domain-policy xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://www.adobe.com/xml/schemas/PolicyFile.xsd">
  <site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="master-only"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

The "Master Only" directive prevents any other file from being read, even if they have the correct content type.  The MIME type of this file should be `text/x-cross-domain-policy`

Comment: How can Flash files appear in origin of your domain if user doesn't have an option to upload files to it's origin?

Answer (score 1):

If you are worried about users uploading swfs you may also want to set:
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff

And you easily check the first few bytes of the file to determine if its a flash.